# DDoS Detection devices available in the market?

Tags: attack-prevention, ddos, detection

Wanted to know what DDoS detection devices are currently available in the market.My organisation has its dedicated firewalls and routers.But we wanted to know if there are any devices in the market which can prevent DDoS.We are already in talks with the ISP to see if they can help us on this.But also wanted to know if there is something that i can use in my infrastructure.

Comment: Are you looking for something that can *detect* a DDoS, or something that can *prevent* a DDoS?  They're two very different things.

Comment: https://www.cloudflare.com/

Comment: DDoS detection is extremely simple; when your users start screaming because your site/app isn't loading then you know you're attacked. ;)

Comment: This is a question very easily answered with a google search. Assuming that you've done that, what additional information can we provide?

Comment: I did not put the question right.Sorry about that.I wanted to know if there is a something in the market that can be used to prevent DDOS attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Detection is fairly easy and a well-known problem that your security and incident event monitoring solutions (SIEM) should be able to shine light on, AlienVault (OSSIM) is an example of such a solution, as is Prelude, via event correlation. It's worth keeping up on correlation as an art unto itself:
https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=1,5&as_vis=1&q=event+correlation+for+ddos&scisbd=1

The short answer regarding prevention is probably 'no' at this present time albeit vendors like Juniper, Qualys and Cisco will claim to provide DDos mitigation features:
http://www.juniper.net/us/en/products-services/security/ddos/

Depending on the bandwidth available to your infrastructure, at some point you would need to replicate the ability to prevent an attack as per commercial offerings that employ scrubbing centres such as Akamai (formerely Prolexic), Incapsula, CloudFlare, Nexusguard, ArborNetworks and so on.

Scrubbing centers explained and pitched by Akamai/Prolexic:
http://www.prolexic.com/why-prolexic-best-dos-and-ddos-scrubbing-centers.html

These companies can mitigate attacks of significant size. More information on size here:
http://www.csoonline.com/article/2876763/network-security/ddos-attack-size-up-50-fold-over-past-decade.html
http://blog.radware.com/security/2012/02/ddos-attacks-myths/

So the question is also one of risk, i.e. the likelihood that your particular company should expect an attack and the scale of that attack based on your activities, locations of operation in terms of markets and where your infrastructure is located as well as the financial impact to you or benefit to the attacker(s) such as brand damage:
http://www.ccul.org/research/2013/13_0531ARiskBasedApproachtoDDoS.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel.The link shared by you were really helpful.